# Animate constraint change not working

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view and I want to move it according to its top spacing constraint inside the animation block.

This is the code I use. The constraint is changing, but the frame is still the same; what should I do?

I have an `IBOutlet` to the constraint named: `topConstraint`

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        self.topConstraint.constant -= 80 ;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

I have read everything about this, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried:

```
 [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

Comment: calling self.view.layoutIfNeeded() is enough

Answer (score 1):

This is what it worked for me in Swift 3

```
self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0,
                       animations: {
                        self.horizontalCenterConstraint.constant = -23
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.topConstraint.constant = newValue;
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

[UIView animateWithDuration: animationDuration
                      delay: animationDelay
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations: ^(void)
                    {
                        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                    }
                 completion: nil];
```